# Berksfile.lock ignored?

Tags: chef-infra, berksfile

I have the following `Berksfile` in my `app/` directory:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"
cookbook "apt", "~> 3.0.0"
cookbook "nodejs", "~> 2.2"
```

When I run `berks install` (version 4.3.3), I get:

```
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
Using apt (3.0.0)
...
```

My app directory contains a `Berksfile.lock` that contains the following line

```
apt (3.0.0)
```

In my initial `Berksfile` I remove the `cookbook apt` line (line 2). I expect berks to use my `Berksfile.lock`. But instead, when I run `berks install` again I get:

```
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
Using apt (4.0.0)
```

And my `Berksfile.lock` gets updated with the new `apt` version. 
Is this the expected behaviour? I would expect this behaviour with the `berks update` command...

Answer (score 1):

Because you have removed the version constraint Berks will now locate and use the newest available version that will satisfy all of the version requirements specified by the cookbooks it manages. Apparently in your case apt version 4.0 satisfies all of your third party dependency version requirements.

Comment: More specifically changing a constraint causes that constraint to be re-solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify version constraints in the `Berksfile`, but use `metadata.rb` instead. This also ensures that the correct version is used when running `chef-client`.